How to prove that the dependent variable is explained by the two independent variables (which are correlated)?
I would like to show that the dependent variable Y is mainly explained by the two independent variables (A1 and A2). Theoretically, an increase in A1 increases Y, and an increase in A2 decreases Y. Futhemore, For each sample, typically the larger A1 is, the smaller A2 is, they are correlated, the sum of these two is close to 100%. Both Y, A1 and A2 can be fitted to cubic relationships as the sample units change (Please check the below fig.).

Initially, I predicted Y through multiple regression analysis using A1, A2 and their interaction term, and found that the residuals were small, but there was a pattern in the variation of the residuals with the sample units, which also showed a similar relationship of variation in the cubic function. How to understand about this situation and does this mean that there are other factors affecting Y. (Fig.1 and Fig.2 are two examples.)

Is there any other suitable statistical analysis to justify the interpretation of A1 and A2 on Y?

What does "Samples" mean?  Is it merely an index to identify the $(A_1,A_2,Y)$ triples, or does it have some intrinsic meaning, such as time of observation?

Samples imply different observation sites (or distances).

Well, does that mean the sequence of samples is meaningful or not?  If it's not meaningful, then any patterns you see in these plots are meaningless, too.

You're right, it is meaningful.
